# "No overload matches this call" when trying to use vue-router with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am desperately trying to get vue and vue-router working with typescript and I am consistently running into problems with the router.

Due to restrictions that have been imposed on my team we are unable to use node and packages managers so we're forced to use the script method of installing vue and vue-router:

```
<script src="~/scripts/libs/vue/vue.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/libs/vue-router/vue-router.js"></script>
```

In addition to using the above method of installing vue we are also unable to use any bundling tools, as such import and require() are not available as well.

On its own we have no problems with vue and typescript combined, but when I try to use vue-router for some reason I'm unable to get vue to pickup on the router. When I try to use the router as described in the documentation I get an "No overload matches this call".

When I go down this route I use the following:

```
const homeComponent = { template: "<div>Home</div>" };

const routes = [
    { path: "/", component: homeCompoent }
];

const router = new VueRouter({routes});
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    data: { intl: Resources }
});
```

this is when I start getting typescript problems because of a missing overload for router. I've also tried to follow the example in the documentation and even then I still get an overload error from typescript.

** EDIT **

I think that I've sorted out what the actual problem is, but I'm still at a loss as to the why  its happening, and the how to fix it.

The exact same problem presents its self in other libraries that I've been trying to utilize, where typescript seems to be the problem. In the case of vue-router the actual problem is that the `Vue` object doesn't contain a definition for the router object, so naturally when I try and use that object, like the documentation indicates, typescript throws an error. Now I do have the type definitions for vue-router, but from what I can see the type definitions are either not being used, or there's an error that's preventing them from updating the `Vue` object correctly

Comment: Did you find out how to use the router in your component ? I am having the same issue in vue-cli

Comment: @Thelord for me it was a problem with the type definitions and where they were looking for vue from. we had to manually tweak the tyepdef for vue-router to make it work correctly, but I'm not certain if that would work for you if you're using the cli

Answer (score 0):

You don't define a component, you just supply an object. It doesn't have `ComponentOptions` defined, so it fails. Just make it a component (and spell things correctly)

```
const homeComponent = Vue.component('home-component', {
  template: '<div>Home</div>'
})
```

Now it's a proper component and will have `ComponentOptions`, so you won't get an error regarding `matched` being undefined (which is a property of this.$router):

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: homeComponent }
];
```

Comment: Even after the change you suggested this still causes the the same error.